# How to terminate processing within actor receive?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am currently having some huge if blocks within the receive methods of my akka actors. Example:

```
def receive = {
  case Alarm(msg) => 
    if (msg != null) {
      [... huge amount of code ...]
    } else {
      logger.log("false alarm")
    }
}
```

Since I think this is not the best readable code, I was wondering if I can do something like that.

```
def receive = {
  case Alarm(msg) =>
    if (msg == null) {
      logger.log("false alarm")
      break // ????? (I know this does not work, but what else?)
    }
    [... huge amount of code ...]
}
```

Any suggestions or best practices?

Edit: Okay I see I have to be more precise. I am having a lot of database queries within the huge amount of code block and dont want to wrap **ALL** those into an if else construct.

Edit2: The thing is, that my actor needs to do a bunch of database operations and that it needs to ensure that each dataset is present before it can process it. I have to do this due to robustness requirements.

Comment: Maybe you should split `Alarm` into several messages?

Comment: `return` instead of `break` should work, but Aleksey's answer is more idiomatic. Can't you wrap the huge amount of code into a private function?

Comment: Sure I can wrap the code, but what does it make any different than moving it to another location ... since the function is not reusable, I can't see any benefits. Edit: fyi using **return** leads to this error _method receive has return statement; needs result type_

Comment: It's a common misconception that you have to create functions only if you plan to reuse your code. Benefits that you get from creating small functions are: easy to read and reason about, easy to test, clear communication of your intents and even documentation by giving good names to functions.

Comment: I see your point. But why should I use Option[T] for variables instead of checking them against **null**? I will have to call **.get** each time I want to access the variable...

Comment: In this case you would use pattern match `Some(value)` instead of calling `get`. It's a bad practice to call `get` on any monad because it can throw. In your example case object would be even more convenient/better

Comment: But imagine a database access object. You call **get(id)** and get back an option. Now you have to check whether this option is empty or not. If empty, do nothing else move on. During you move on you always have to get or match agains Some(value)? o.O

Comment: yep, that's how it's done according to FP. Usually you use functional composition and for comprehensions to make it easy to use and idiomatic. For example: `for { user <- getUser(id); accounts <- getAllAccounts(user) } yield accounts` or something like that. Here `getUser` and `getAllAccounts` return monads similar to `Option` or `Box` in Lift. for comprehension follows a "happy path" and you get back maybe some value or a wrapped error.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the wrapping all queries into if/else part and how it's related to `receive`. Can you reword your question or be more specific? Does your actor receive results of those queries or something else? Please add more details.

Comment: Added some test to my question

Comment: @Coxer I'm sorry but it's not any clearer after 2 edits. Can you delete these 2 edits and formulate your question again?

Comment: Concur that this is really not about akka at all, but about factoring out functions. Maybe re-phrase it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either have if-elses like you already have, or divide it up into different cases:

```
def receive = {
  case Alarm(msg) => 
    if (msg != null) {
      [... huge amount of code ...]
    } else {
      logger.log("false alarm")
    }
}
```

becomes

```
def receive = {
  csae Alarm(null) => logger.log("false alarm")
  case Alarm(msg) => [... huge amount of code ...]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not really Akka related question because the main problem here is pattern matching and complying with return type of `receive`. `receive` is a partial function that has this return type: `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`. So you don't really have to return anything specific from your `if/else` statement. Thus you just can `log` without any sort of `break`.

To improve style you can use one of these ways to write the pattern matching expression:

```
scala> case class Alarm(msg: String)
defined class Alarm

scala> Alarm(null) match {
     |   case Alarm(null) => "Null"
     |   case Alarm(_) => "NOT null"
     | }
res1: String = Null

scala> Alarm(null) match {
     |   case Alarm(smth) if(smth == null) => "Null"
     |   case Alarm(_) => "NOT null"
     | }
res2: String = Null
```

The first option is less verbose and better in this case.

*offtopic*: avoid using `null`, use `Option[T]` instead or `case object`.

*Additional (using case object):*

```
scala> sealed trait AlarmLike
defined trait AlarmLike

scala> case class Alarm(msg: String) extends AlarmLike
defined class Alarm

scala> case object EmptyAlarm extends AlarmLike
defined module EmptyAlarm

scala> val l: List[AlarmLike] = List(Alarm("Ahtung!"), EmptyAlarm)
l: List[AlarmLike] = List(Alarm(Ahtung!), EmptyAlarm)

scala> l map { case Alarm(desc) => desc; case EmptyAlarm => "EmptyAlarm" }
res0: List[String] = List(Ahtung!, EmptyAlarm)
```

Comment: My example was just for illustration. What I need is to prevent the reminder of a case of a receive function to be omitted.